# Aws lambda logs monitor by log groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

My lambda logs arranged by date,for example 051223
Is there a way to create metric that monitor the errors in the log group by type?
For example all the errors in the same day log group.
I was able to do something similar,
Only for the situation  where I write all the logs in one place.
But it's not relevant because I want the logs to be sorted by date in log groups.

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how Cloudwatch was designed. 
From the docs:
> You can use metric filters to extract metric observations from ingested events and transform them to data points in a CloudWatch metric. Metric filters are assigned to log groups, and all of the filters assigned to a log group are applied to their log streams.

Any particular reason why you don't want it in one log group? 
You can order the streams in the group by creation or last event time. Would that not suite your use case?